# How to search the Ruby GraphQL query document (AST) for field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, abstract-syntax-tree, graphql-ruby

I am trying to search the Ruby GraphQL query document for the node related to the particular field.

https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/2.0.20/GraphQL/Language/Nodes.html

I've been looking through the above API docs to find something to help but couldn't find a function to help search through the nodes.

I could have sworn that before the weekend I had been able to use something like the following:

```
context.query.document.node('myField')
```

But today it seems like I must have imagined that.

I'm doing it know with a manual search function (probably could be better):

```
# query_nodes = context.query.document.children

def find_my_field(query_nodes)
  return_value = nil
  query_nodes.each do |node|
    my_field = node.children.find { |field| field.name == 'myField' }
    if my_field.nil?
      return_value = find_my_field(node.children)
    else
      return_value = my_field
      break
    end
  end
  return_value
end
```

Is there a way to simply query for the node like in my first example?